# setting margin-top according to header size? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a page with a fixed header that varies in size when the browser window changes (let's say from a pc to a mobile phone). So far I got it to work fine, but now I have content I want to place underneath it and I don't want to set it on a fixed margin (because then the header will cover the top of the content when it jumps into two lines).

Is there a way to do this using html/css?

Another way to do this would probably be to set up a placeholding element, but same problem as before, how do you resize it according to the header size?

here's my code

```css
.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    height:3em;
    text-align:center;
}
/* logo positioning */
#logo{
    display:inline-block;
}
/* napis na headerju */
#headersign{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:160%;
}
/* top menubar */
#topmenu {
    background-color:#009933;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:verdana;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
/* text menubar */
.menutext {
    font-family:verdana;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.menutext:hover {
    color:#cccccc;
}
/* text position menubar */
#linkijs{
   float:left;
   display:inline;
   margin-left:1%;
}
#linkeng{
   float:right;
   display:inline;
   margin-right:1%;
}
/* podatki o knjižnici */
#leftpanel {
    /*positioning*/
    top:0;
    margin-left:15%;
    background-color:#00cc66;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img id="logo" src="images/ijs_logo.gif" alt="logo" />
            <p id="headersign">ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</p>
            <div id="topmenu">
                <a href="http://www.ijs.si/"><p class="menutext" id="linkijs">IJS</p></a>
                <a href="indexEN.html"><p class ="menutext" id="linkeng">ENGLISH</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftpanel">
            <p>
                Institut Jožef Štefan <br />Knjižnica <br/>Jamova 39 <br/>1000 Ljubljana <br/><br/>tel: +386 1 47 73 304 <br/>fax: +386 1 47 73 152 <br/><br/>Delovni čas:<br/>pon-čet: 8:00-17:30<br/>pet: 8:00-17:00
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightpanel">
            
        </div>
    </body>
```

hope I didn't miss a similar post, been trying hard to find a solution whole morning

Comment: you can easily achieve this using jquery, get the height of header on page load and set the margin of content div equal to the height of header you got ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an "hidden" div that initially stay under your header (so with a lower z-index), and  with the same dimension:

`.headerMargin{
    position:initial; 
    width:70%;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    height:3em;
    text-align:center;
}`

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this is what I'll do, will try to copy the exact same header so it'll act the same when resized. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Syed has mentioned in the comments this would be simple with jQuery (and is, I think, not possible with CSS to your exact specifications):

```
$(function(){
    $('.body-element').each(function(){
        var headerHeight=$('.variable-size-header').height();
        // headerHeight+=15; // maybe add an offset too?
        $(this).css('margin-top',headerHeight+'px');
    });
});
```

I've named the element classes as a description because I wasn't 100% certain which of your elements you wanted positioned and which needed the margin; drop that in a comment and I can edit my answer.

Comment: I need to get the .header height and position the #leftpanel div. Thing is I'm not sure I can use javascript on this page, guess I'll just set the margin so it works around the site desing (move the text down a bit inside the container), but this also means I have to make a stylesheet for every page...thanks anyway

Comment: Having one stylesheet per page becomes easy (and the norm) when using a CSS compiler like [SASS](sass-lang.com). Worth investigating to make your CSS more flexible. May I ask why you can't use JavaScript?

Comment: Well it's not that I can't use it, the guy I'm making this for just said if there's a way to make it only css+html do it without js, and I didn't ask why :)
I'll definitely look into sass once I have the time, thanks for the heads up