# How to put video as background of my div?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to play a youtube video as background of my div. I searched online and this is what I found most people did.

```css
.container-fluid{
  padding:0;
}

/* header section */
.header{
  background: #000;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vid-container, .header iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-text{
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
}

.row {
    color: red; /* for debugging */
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .vid-container { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .vid-container { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class = "container-fluid">
<div class="header">
  <div class="vid-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DXA3JYdFKAE? controls=0&showInfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=DXA3JYdFKAE&start=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle orange-tick"></i>
    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-bullseye target"></i>
    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-heart heart"></i>
    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Initially, this made the video fullscreen. So, I changed the header height to 70% and changed the overflow to hidden. But since the header position is fixed, anything I add after the header shows up on top of the header video. And if I remove position : fixed, the video gets messed up. Any ideas on how to do this without making the header fixed?

I added some old html that I wrote to show how any div after "header" goes on top of it.

EDIT:
It seems I have caused some confusion due to the wording in my question. This is my attempt to clarify all doubts. The website presently looks like this:
[this image depicts a header div with a video background using 70% of the viewport height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpR9z.png)
My question is, is there a way I can achieve the same final result without using position fixed for the header?

Comment: "anything I add after the header shows up on top of the header video" This is how *backgrounds* work... what's the issue here?

Comment: Where do you want your header to be? Because now you have setup 0 at everysingle positions. top bottom left and right

Comment: And is the video is supposed to be outside the header? Because so far it's inside (I don't know what you're trying to do so I perform some check lol, be more specific please)

Comment: I want the video to be the background for just the header. Any thing else I add after the "header" div comes on top of the header too.

Comment: @AakashDasgupta Can you please update your code in the question (you can edit the runnable snippet) to include a repro of your scenario? E.g. with more stuff added after the header?

Comment: @TylerH Done, I added some code from some other website to test, and sure enough, it goes on top of the header

Comment: @AakashDasgupta Thanks. It seems the code goes underneath, not on top of. Perhaps you're just describing the problem awkwardly. Is your issue that you want the text to *stop scrolling* beyond the bottom border of the header?

Comment: @TylerH this is weird, because on my browser, the code goes on top, but in the snippet it goes underneath. Maybe because I'm using bootstrap in my document and have not included it in the snippet? And I want the code to show underneath the header, like how a normal HTML document would flow.

Comment: @AakashDasgupta Yes, that would make a difference. You can edit the snippet to add an external link to bootstrap's CDN URL (and any other libraries you are using, if necessary)

Comment: I am not being able to, the CDN is too long to be formatted properly. But I would really appreciate if you could help me with this issue. Just show me how to get the text below the header, like a normal HTML document flow. And as for external libraries, I'm only using bootstrap

Comment: @AakashDasgupta I've updated the post to include the Bootstrap CDN. before I can help you I need an answer to my previous clarification question - do you want the `.row` text to stop moving "up" when it meets the bottom edge of the header?

Comment: @TylerH Yes that's what I want

Comment: @AakashDasgupta Gotcha. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379434/setting-margin-top-according-to-header-size-html-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290118/offset-content-top-margin-based-on-height-of-fixed-header for some solutions for that. Essentially you will need to give your `.row` a margin-top equal to the height of the header.

Comment: This is not exactly the solution I was looking for. You see the video stays fixed at the top of the webpage. But I want it to scroll like it would normally do, without position : fixed. But any solution I find on how to implement background video, position: fixed is always present. I was hoping for an alternate way to get fullscreen video so that when I scroll, the video does not stay fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a position to your content. I set it up to absolute to work with your exemple, but you can use relative if the parent is positioned in absolute.
Then I just push the content 70% from top.

Now, I assume you want your header to go over your content when you scroll. Then I suggest you to set his z-index value to 100 (10 or even 1 will work but that way you're pretty sure to never override it with another div)

```css
.container-fluid{
  padding:0;
}

/* header section */
.header{
  background: #000;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:100; /* here the z-index set up for the header to overlap everything */
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vid-container, .header iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-text{
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
}

.row {
    color: red; /* for debugging */
}

/* Here we set the content poisitoning to absolute and top coordinate = to the height of the header */

.row {
  position:absolute;
  top:70%;
}

/**/

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .vid-container { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .vid-container { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class = "container-fluid">
<div class="header">
  <div class="vid-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DXA3JYdFKAE? controls=0&showInfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=DXA3JYdFKAE&start=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle orange-tick"></i>
    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-bullseye target"></i>
    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 feature">
    <i class="fas fa-heart heart"></i>
    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Anyway, may I suggest you to try with `position:absolute` instead of fixed? I am not sure if that's the effect you try to get. So let me know.

Comment: No you see, I want the video to scroll along with the webpage. That's why I wanted a method to get the same fullscreen video without using position: fixed. And using absolute, the video disappears completely

Comment: Then do a drawing of what you want please, because it's stil not clear enough. What you want is `position: sticky` I presume?

Comment: The iframe of your video have Absolute position, and remove the top value of the .vid-container, remove it and put position to absolute instead of fixed to the header

Comment: I mean, remove it (the position absolute of your iframe)